# Do the modern compilers optimize unsigned int use in for loops?

Tags: c++, c, compilation, unsigned-integer

Consider the following code:

```
for(unsigned i = 0; i < counter1; i++) {
    for(unsigned j = 0; j < counter2; j++) {
        // some code here
    }
}
```

Are there any benefits of using `unsigned int` instead of just `int` in this context? Would a modern compiler optimize it somehow or is the only benefit just the larger size of `unsigned int`?

Comment: What kind of benefit are you thinking of? On most (all?) systems, the example you give will emit exactly the same code for either type anyway.

Comment: As Leushenko said. If you are preoccupied by this sort of question, you simply need to learn to read the assembly generated by the compiler, otherwise you cannot make sense of the answers even if you get them. Conversely, once you are more familiar with the instruction set, it will be obvious to you that nearly the same instructions end up being generated for `int` and `unsigned int`. With GCC, the option to obtain the assembly is `-S`.

Comment: To add a slight dissent to the above and below, *optimizing* compilers are known to generate slightly different assembly code for int versus unsigned int for loops.  GCC has outstanding bugs related to this.  So for high-level purposes, there is no effective difference.  But if you are looking at true real-time performance, then like @Couq mentioned you need to look at the assembly language of the the same loop implemented with int and with unsigned int.  Note that in rare cases, longer assembly code does not necessarily mean longer loop time (for example see: http://warppipe.net/blog/?p=498).

Comment: With `<=` instead of `<`, it could make a difference, as using a unsigned integer no longer guarantees the loop isn't infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in the compiler result for these loops, because in assembly unsigned integers aren't really treated differently in most cases, except for comparisons. The bugs [therainmaker mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29194220/248065) are relevant in other cases though.

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned buffer[100][100];

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            fprintf(stdout, "i");
}
$ sed s/unsigned/int/ test.c  > testint.c
$ gcc -std=c11 -O3 testint.c -S; gcc -std=c11 -O3 test.c -S
$ diff test.s testint.s
1c1
<   .file   "test.c"
---
>   .file   "testint.c"
```

If I use `-O0` you'll see a difference when branching:

```
$ diff test.s testint.s
1c1
<   .file   "test.c"
---
>   .file   "testint.c"
27c27
<   jbe .L4
---
>   jle .L4
31c31
<   jbe .L5
---
>   jle .L5
```

Comment: `jbe` and `jle` cost the same though, so the differences in generated assembly do not even correspond to differences in execution time with `-O0`.

Answer (score 9):

There is no advantage of using `unsigned int` in a for loop over `int`. The marginal gain in the range of numbers using `unsigned int` is far outweighed by the chance to introduce bugs. Also, `unsigned int` makes readability harder.

An interesting case where bugs may be introduced is

```
for (unsigned int i = foo.Length()-1; i >= 0; --i) ...
```

As you may notice, this loop will never end. Some modern gcc compilers may provide warnings in such cases, but sometimes they don't. Some bugs can also occur in comparing `signed` and `unsigned` values. If you need the extra space, better use a `long` instead of `unsigned int`.

Specifically talking about compiler optimisations with `unsigned int`, there isn't any gain.

Comment: There is no marginal gain in the size. An `unsigned int` is the exact same size as an `int` on every compiler I've ever seen

Comment: Well, if you want to run a loop between 2^31 and 2^32 times, the unsigned int is easier to use (especially if the number of iterations is based on user input and you want the number of iterations to be able to get big).

Comment: @jalf: I meant the marginal gain in being able to go upto 2^32 as opposed to 2^31 with an int. Editing it.

Comment: @MonKeePoo: It is extremely unlikely that you will have a case where you need to run a loop between 2^31 and 2^32. And if you have to, you can go ahead with an unsigned int, provided you know what you are doing. I'm not saying one should never use them. All I am saying that it is not worth using them all the time.

Comment: @therainmaker Yeah, it's a pretty specific scenario, I'll give you that. But in any case where the user gives the number of iterations, I would use an usigned int, just to provide a bigger range to the user (even if they probably won't need it).